# Bad Gateway if Backend Server is behind VPN

Tags: traefik, openvpn

I have traefik 1.6.5 installed and all my frontend and backend servers are running fine, except on backend which is behind a openvpn tunnel. In this setup I always get "Bad Gateway"

If I connect the same service without vpn the backend works find.

Any idea what I can do on that.

The following is my frontend / backend config

```
[backends.c00614]
 [backends.c00614.servers.server1]
   url = "http://172.18.20.41:81"
[frontends.c00614]
  backend = "c00614"
  passHostHeader = true
  [frontends.c00614.routes.route1]
      rule = "Host:c00614.test.xxxxxx.xx"
  [frontends.c00614.headers.customrequestheaders]
    X-Forwarded-Proto = "https"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using docker, you can try running the alpine image (traefik:1.6.5-alpine). This will allow you to open a shell and ping/curl your backend URL. If you cannot access the URL over the vpn from the docker shell, then the issue is with your networking, not the Traefik app.

Thanks!